# CLT-based confidence intervals not working in code

Tags: sampling, mean, central-limit-theorem, bernoulli-distribution

I wrote code to draw $n$ samples from a categorically distributed random variable $C$ with probabilities $p_i$ for each value $i$ and to use those samples to compute an approximation $q_i = n_i/n$ of the real probabilities, where $n_i$ is the number of times value $i$ has been drawn.

To test the code, I am using the Central Limit Theorem to compute a near-100% confidence interval for $q_i$.

To do that, I define a Bernoulli variable $B_i = [C=i]$, where $[]$ denotes an indicator function. The standard deviation of $B_i$ is $p_i(1-p_i)$. By the Central Limit Theorem, $q_i$ will be normally distributed with standard deviation $\sigma_{q_i}=p_i(1-p_i)/\sqrt{n}$. Therefore $q_i$ should be in $[p_i - 3.5\sigma_{q_i}, p_i + 3.5\sigma_{q_i}]$ nearly 100% of the time, according to the normal distribution tables.

However, when I run code to simulate all that, I find that $q_i$ falls out of that interval rather often (around a tenth of the time).

Am I missing something here? Could this be due to poor pseudo-random number generation? I sampled in two different ways (using Python's `random` and PyTorch) and the results were similar.

**Update**: I realize now that I am treating each value as independent Bernoulli distributions but of course they are not independent since the multinomial variable is equal to a single value in each sample. So the question now becomes: how can I compute the confidence interval for the empirical probabilities measured in this way?

**Update 2**: I had placed the code below, but please note this is completely optional information, since I've described what I was doing above. Still leaving the code for reference. In it, I assume the specific case in which $p$ is proportional to $(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)$ and $n = 10,000$. For convenience, I check estimates against the largest confidence interval for all values, instead of using the confidence interval for each value (this should make it even less likely to have estimates out of the checked interval).

````python
import math

import torch


def test_torch_categorical_sampling():

    def bernoulli_std_err(p, n):
        return p * (1 - p) / math.sqrt(n)

    masses = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    probabilities = torch.tensor(masses, dtype=torch.float)/sum(masses)
    n = 10000
    std_errors = torch.tensor([bernoulli_std_err(p, n) for p in probabilities])
    max_std_error = max(std_errors)
    pretty_much_100_percent_range = 3.5 * max_std_error

    categorical = torch.distributions.Categorical(probabilities)
    pytorch_sampling_function = lambda: categorical.sample()

    for trials in range(100):
        test_clt(pytorch_sampling_function, probabilities, n, pretty_much_100_percent_range)


def test_clt(sampling_function, probabilities, n, pretty_much_100_percent_range):
    count = get_sampling_count_per_value(n, sampling_function)
    empirical_probabilities = torch.tensor(count, dtype=torch.float) / n
    print(f"     Real probabilities: {probabilities}")
    print(f"Empirical probabilities: {empirical_probabilities}")
    violation = torch.where(abs(empirical_probabilities - probabilities) > pretty_much_100_percent_range)[0]
    if len(violation) > 0:
        print(f"Violation at index {violation}")
        print(f"Empirical is {empirical_probabilities[violation]}, real is {probabilities[violation]}")
        print(f"Difference is {abs(empirical_probabilities[violation] - probabilities[violation])}")
        print(f"100% range is {pretty_much_100_percent_range:.10f}")
        raise Exception("CLT apparently violated")


def get_sampling_count_per_value(n, sampling_function):
    count = [0] * 6
    for i in range(n):
        sampled_value = sampling_function()
        count[sampled_value] += 1
    return count


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_torch_categorical_sampling()
```
````

Comment: What is a near-100% confidence interval?

Comment: As a rule, suspect your own code before you suspect the pseudorandom number generator: you will usually save a lot of time with this hypothesis.  I suspect most readers on this site won't have much of a taste for debugging your code, nor will they on [SO].  What can you do to reduce this to a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @Dave, a near-100% is a confidence interval containing the exact mean with almost certainty (say 99,999% of the time). In a normal distribution this corresponds to something like mean +- 3.5 standard deviation.

Comment: @whuber: thanks, that makes sense. Please note the code here is just optional additional information. I've described the entire method I was using mathematically and that should be enough to determine what I am doing wrong. In fact I think I've figured it out: I am treating the multinomial variable being equal to each value as independent Bernoulli distributions but of course they are dependent on each other; one and only one of them will be true for each sample. I will update the question accordingly.